# Restkit, disable caching

Tags: ios, restkit

I've got a really hard time to try disabling caching in the Restkit framework.
I've try to put the cache policy to none, with no effect at all. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So once you've got a client, either explicitly initializing it:

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:url];
```

or by letting the object manager do it:

```
RKObjectManager* om = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:url];
RKClient *client = om.client;
```

It should be a simple matter of just setting the cache policy:

```
client.cachePolicy = RKRequestCachePolicyNone;
```

Was that what you were doing?

**Update:** Since the logging message is the only thing worrying I decided to track down its source. The tl;dr version is to ignore the message and trust what the logging proxy is telling you.

To double check I searched for "Invalidating cache at path" and found it in two locations `RKCache invalidateSubDirectory:` and `RKCache invalidateAll` and set break points on them. Here's a partial stack trace from some of my code:

```
#0  0x000e6c66 in -[RKCache invalidateSubDirectory:] at RestKit/Code/Support/RKCache.m:189
#1  0x0006b767 in -[RKRequestCache invalidateWithStoragePolicy:] at RestKit/Code/Network/RKRequestCache.m:237
#2  0x0006b958 in -[RKRequestCache setStoragePolicy:] at RestKit/Code/Network/RKRequestCache.m:253
#3  0x00069abf in -[RKRequestCache initWithPath:storagePolicy:] at RestKit/Code/Network/RKRequestCache.m:60
#4  0x000586f3 in -[RKClient baseURLDidChange:] at RestKit/Code/Network/RKClient.m:339
#5  0x000589ce in -[RKClient observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] at RestKit/Code/Network/RKClient.m:373
#6  0x0183cd91 in NSKeyValueNotifyObserver ()
#7  0x0183c895 in NSKeyValueDidChange ()
#8  0x0182233e in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] ()
#9  0x01844a82 in _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify ()
#10 0x00057404 in -[RKClient initWithBaseURL:] at RestKit/Code/Network/RKClient.m:176
#11 0x00056df3 in +[RKClient clientWithBaseURL:] at RestKit/Code/Network/RKClient.m:130
```

What I learned looking through this is that there are two enums that control caching:

- `RKRequestCachePolicy` which is what you set on the client, it controls when the cache is consulted.
- `RKRequestCacheStoragePolicy` which determines how long the results are stored on the device (never, duration of session, permanent).

As part of setting up the client, when a URL is set the client creates a new cache with `RKRequestCacheStoragePolicyPermanently` setting the storage policy involves clearing out the previous session cache and—if caching is disabled—the permanent cache. It's that clearing that you're seeing in the logging messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried, and still got the message  "restkit.support:RKCache.m:178 Invalidating cache at path:"

Comment: Is that the only thing that suggests it's caching? Have you tried using Charles or another logging proxy to see what's going out to the server?

Comment: I've tried the proxy logging, nothing goes wrong, i did receive the expected datas of the server. In fact, nothing goes wrong in the behaviour of the app, my datas are good, everything goes as expected. But, my logger keep give me those messages "Invalidating cache at path : ....". It's look like restkit try to remove cache existing file, but can't.
As said, i'm just worried that those actions aren't good for the performance, or Apple validation.

Comment: I just updated my answer with more information. The short version is it's doing exactly what it should and there's no need to worry. Why don't you want **any** caching?

Comment: First one : i needed to debug, and it's annoying to see it full of this message
Second one : a big part of the app (about 60-70%) works in real time.

Comment: @Gael.D do you feel this question has been answered? It seems like you already confirmed that caching was disabled a few comments back. Any thing else I can do?

Comment: The question is indeed answering. The problem is like the truth, out there :)