# RestKit throws NSInternalInconsistencyException upon PUT request

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, restkit

My app crashes with an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, when issuing a `PUT` request in the following manner:

- Download profile information through `HTTP GET`
- Update the profile on the client
- Upload the changes through `HTTP PUT`
- Parse the body of the `PUT` response body again

#### The error I get

> 2015-05-27 17:27:17.796 XYZ[17093:2526798] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot add object with entity 'Company' to cache for entity of 'Company''

The error come from here [RKEntityByAttributeCache.m#L333](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/CoreData/RKEntityByAttributeCache.m#L333):

```
 NSAssert([entity isKindOfEntity:self.entity], @"Cannot add object with entity '%@' to cache for entity of '%@'", [entity name], [self.entity name]);
```

Curiously now, the `entity` and the `self.entity` object both have the same debug description. So I don't know how the `NSEnityDescriptor` of these two instances can possibly vary.

#### Things I've tried so far

- Remove the app from the simulator: I can then update it **once** and from then on I get the error as described above again.
- Remove the `NSAssert` statement: The `PUT` operation now works fine.
- <del>Disable caching as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11582347/784318)</del> (In Restkit 0.24.1 this seems to no longer be possible)

#### My Mappings

I did implement my mappings as extensions to `RKManagedObjectStore` as follows:

```
extension RKManagedObjectStore{
    var companyMapping: RKEntityMapping{
        let mapping = RKEntityMapping(
            forEntityForName: "Company",
            inManagedObjectStore: self
        )
        mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray(
            ["id", "name"]
        )
        mapping.identificationAttributes = ["id"]

        return mapping
    }

    var profileMapping: RKEntityMapping{
        let mapping = RKEntityMapping(
            forEntityForName: "Profile",
            inManagedObjectStore: self
        )
        mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray(
            ["id", "content", "language", "profileImageId" ]
        )
        mapping.identificationAttributes = ["id"]
        mapping.addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath("companies", mapping: companyMapping)

        return mapping
    }
}
```

#### Data I post to the server and get back in the response in the same format:

```
{
    "content": "XYZ",
    "id": "profile-1",
    "language": "de",
    "companies": [{
        "id": "company-1",
        "name": "Somecompany Inc."
    }]
}
```

### Update `NSMangedObectContext`

Since the issue seems to be related to multiple `NSManagedObjectContext`s, here is how I setup RestKit and the MOCs:

```
init(baseURL: String, dataModelName: String){

    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(dataModelName, withExtension: "momd")!
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    self.managedObjectStore = RKManagedObjectStore(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

    let storePath = RKApplicationDataDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(dataModelName).sqlite")

    var error: NSError? = nil
    managedObjectStore.addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath(storePath,
        fromSeedDatabaseAtPath: nil,
        withConfiguration: nil,
        options: nil,
        error: &error
    )
    if let e = error{
        // Omitted: Delete the SQLite store and re-create it
    }
    managedObjectStore.createManagedObjectContexts()
    managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache(
        managedObjectContext: managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext
    )
    objectManager = RKObjectManager(baseURL: NSURL(string: baseURL))
    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore
    objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    super.init(baseURL: baseURL)

    setupMapping()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Curiously now, the entity and the self.entity object both have the same debug description.

The addresses of the entity descriptions must be different.

This usually happens when you tamper with the managed object context that RestKit is using so the entities that are compared come from 2 different contexts and are therefore different, or when you directly pass a managed object from the wrong context.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by **addresses**. I did not find this in [`NSEntityDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/index.html).

Comment: The pointers - they are different instances. The descriptions of the entity names are the same but the underlying contexts are different...

Comment: Okay, this sounds reasonable, but now when I post my object and then parse the response and map it back to my original object, how can I make sure, that the two contexts don't interfere with each other? Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using separate contexts? You should generally keep things simple and work from the main context and allow RestKit to deal with any other contexts required...

Comment: I don't explicitly want to deal with multiple contexts, please see my updated answer and how I setup RestKit

Comment: Have you checked your setup code isn't inadvertently run again? Your code looks ok but it does depend on how it's used

Comment: This fixed my problem, I was accidentally creating multiple contexts for each services so I changed this and the problems dissapeared

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an ManagedObjectStore. I doubt `self` is correct as a parameter. I infer from your explanation that self is a subclass of NSManagedObject, i.e. the entity you want to map, `Company` or `Profile` however you need an `RKManagedObjectStore` and pass this as the second parameter.

```
let mapping = RKEntityMapping(
    forEntityForName: "Profile",
    inManagedObjectStore: <pointer to the RKManagedObjectStore>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I created an extension to `RKManagedObjectStore` to implement my mappings so self refers to an actual object store. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I usually extend the entities but I guess this is up to everyone.